# change color of background and text with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, colors, onclick

I want to keep it simple on my simple html page. 1 button to cycle background colors, 1 button to cycle text colors.

I found some code here on stackoverflow that works, for the background:

```
<script>
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>

    <body id='body'>
    <button onclick="changeColor();">Change color</button>
    </body>
```

and then I found some other code that was similar, that could be used along the other code, for the text color, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
function changeColor(){
var element = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
element.className = "myClass";
}
.myClass{
 color:red; 
 }
</script>

<div id="questionContainer"> 
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
  </div>
 <button onclick="changeColor()">COLORCHANGER<button>
```

I can't get it to work. pulling my hair out.

I tried either code block by itself in a plain .html for testing. the one for background works, the one for text does not.

Comment: Its a typo: You are missing / in `</button>` so change `<button>` to `</button>`

Comment: why is there CSS rule in a script tag?

Comment: you know I am a n00b, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by doing following steps:

1. Separated the background and text into two different functions due to the need for two different arrays;
2. Deleted unnecessary reference to `.myclass` in [style] and [script] tags, it held the color on red and didn't use an array;
3. Added preconditions for body and text styles to demonstrate it doesn't ignore those or is defeated by those;
4. Modified variable names;
5. Added a style statement to [body] tag since the function changes the `backgroundColor` value of the style of the element defined by var col;
6. Changed `col.style.color` to `element.style.color` as required by var element

**The Code:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body, html {
        margin: 10;
        }
        
        .txt1 {
        font-family: 'lucida console';
        color:white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="body" style=background-color:black;>

    <script>
        var bcols = ["red", "blue", "green"];
        var bcolsi = 0;
        function changeBcol() {
            var col = document.getElementById("body");
            if( bcolsi >= bcols.length ) {
                bcolsi = 0;
            }
            col.style.backgroundColor = bcols[bcolsi];
            bcolsi++; 
            }
    </script>

    <script>
        var tcols = ["red", "blue", "green"];
        var tcolsi = 0;
        function changeTcol() {
            var element = document.getElementById("testText");
            if( tcolsi >= tcols.length ) {
                tcolsi = 0;
            }
            element.style.color = tcols[tcolsi];
            tcolsi++; 
            }
    </script>

    <button onclick="changeBcol();">change background color</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="changeTcol();">change text color</button>

    <div id="testText" class="txt1">
        TEST TEXT
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the CSS class inside the `script` block. `script` block is meant for javascript code only. I have edited your 2nd piece of code as follows

```
<script>
    function changeColor(){
        var element = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
        element.className = "myClass";
    }
</script>
<style>
.myClass{
   color:red; 
}
</style>

<div id="questionContainer"> 
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME? 
</em></strong></p>
</div>
<button onclick="changeColor()">COLORCHANGER<button>
```

Comment: using the <script>...</script> inside the <style> tags didn't work. moved the script to after the </style> tag and left the .myclass within <style> tags did work! you saved me from early baldness

Comment: now how would I combine those to have 2 buttons, one for background and the other for text? they both use the same "function changeColor ()"

Comment: You should combine them something like this                                                        
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
  
  var element = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
        element.className = "myClass";
    }

Comment: doing that, either button changes both the text and background to red. subsequent button presses (of either) cycle through background colors.